# Mod Rewrite goes in conflict with Wordpress rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

in my website there is a page with a shortcode that reads 3 parameters before to print the content. The page looks like the following:

> /collaboratori?collaboratore=6&n=Mario&c=Rossi

I want to transform it in a **SEO friendly url** like this:

> /profilo-collaboratore/6/Mario/Rossi

I'm using the following **Mod Rewrite rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profilo-collaboratore/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /collaboratori?collaboratore=$1&n=$2&c=$3 [L]
```

But when I try to load /profilo-collaboratore/6/Mario/Rossi the web server returns a **404 error code** and Wordpress shows me a 404 error page

My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profilo-collaboratore/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /collaboratori?collaboratore=$1&n=$2&c=$3 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where I wrong?

Thank you so much

Comment: Should the url be handled by Wordpress at all (e.g. is it a wordpress plugin) or not?

Comment: Yes it's a plugin written by me

Comment: Wordpress relies on the url as it is in the address bar rather than the url it is rewritten to. This means that rewriting the url with mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: [this might be of some help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69768/how-to-rewrite-wordpress-url-for-a-plugin)

Comment: and how can I do it? Do you have some examples?

Comment: The linked question might be of some help. I am not very familiar with wordpress, so I can't help you any further than telling you that mod_rewrite is at least not the way to go. You might want to search some more on wordpress.stackexchange as that is probably not the only related question you might find there.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the regex is having the issue.

Try below rule, it should work.

```
RewriteRule ^/profilo-collaboratore/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+) /collaboratori?collaboratore=$1&n=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

I tested it by adding `[R]` flag to see the rewritten url during redirection.

```
$ curl -IL http://localhost/profilo-collaboratore/6/Mario/Rossi
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 15:03:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e
Location: http://localhost/collaboratori?collaboratore=6&n=Mario&c=Rossi
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 15:03:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 08:11:27 GMT
ETag: "13f-50af1d6a1b74d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 319
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Hi Kannan,

thank you but it doesn't work. How said before by @Sumurai8, it's a conflict with Wordpress rewrite rules, in its engine. It's not a problem that can be solved by using .htaccess.

I will update the question if I will find a solution